# Vanilla PHP, Order status class [INTERNET STORE PROJECT]

Tags: php

I need to write an order status class (file Status.php), which will contain certain statuses of an order in my internet store, which I am currently working on.

Desired statuses are:
-Pending (User still haven't confirmed items in the basket).
-Confirmed (User confirmed items in the basket as his order).
-Paid (User has paid for items he bought)
-Complete (Items were sent to user via post office)

It's probably very simple task, but I don't know how to start my work and build this class.

This is my Status.php code so far:

```
<?php

class Status {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    function __construct() {
        $this->id = -1;
        $this->name = "";
    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
    function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}

?>
```

Big thanks to everyone who helps under this post :).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I can't understand what exactly your problem is. Can you please add more details ?

Comment: I can't crack the logic which stays behind these statuses. How to write them correctly and how this class should work. My problem doesn't only contain syntax unfamiliarity, but also an overall idea, how to build a class like this.

@Edit -> Store should work like this -> while user adds items to the basket, these items are marked as Pending, and so on.

I Don't know if I'm specific enough, if not, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't know how to start my work and build this class.

The code you posted is not a class but some procedural code disguised as OOP. Let's assume I create an object of type `Status`:

```
$status = new Status();
```

Is this an object? What is the value of this new object? It looks like an object but it is just some empty memory. No data, no behaviour, just useless code.

The constructor of a properly implemented class constructs the object, prepares it for usage. When the constructor returns, the object must be fully set; no further `$status->setId()` and `$status->setName()` should be required.

This is how I suggest you to define your class:

```
class Status {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        // Validate arguments; an object must always be valid
        if (! is_int($id) || $id <= 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$id must be a positive non-zero number.');
        }
        if (! is_string($name) || empty($name)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$name must be a non-empty string.');
        }

        // The arguments are valid; go ahead and construct the object
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Now let's create some `Status` objects:

```
$pending   = new Status(1, 'pending');
$confirmed = new Confirmed(2, 'confirmed');
```

Depending on how you plan to use the properties of the objects, you will probably not pass the ID as argument to the constructor but generate it internally or use a fixed list of values.

Or you can go one step further, declare the properties and the constructor of class `Status` as `protected` and create one child class for each possible value of `$status`:

```
class Status {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected function __construct($id, $name) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

class Pending extends Status {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(1, 'pending');
    }
}

class Confirmed extends Status {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(2, 'confirmed');
    }
}

class Paid extends Status {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(3, 'paid');
    }
}
```

The properties are `protected` to allow the methods of the children classes access them (when they are `private` only the methods of class `Status` see them). The constructor is `protected` to prevent the creation of objects of type `Status` but allow the methods of the children classes (their constructors actually) invoke it. **Always call the constructor of the parent class in the constructor of the child class.**

This way, when you need to create an object that represents a status, all you have to do is:

```
$pending   = new Pending();
$confirmed = new Confirmed();
// a.s.o.
```

Don't rush to add the "getters" (the methods that access the object properties and provides the to the client code) you defined in your code. Think what do you want to do with the values stored in a `Status` object and check if that code can stay in the `Status` class too. Put code specific to the "pending" status (f.e.) into the `Pending` class, not into the `Status` class.

If `Status::$name` is used only for display then you better implement [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) instead of `getName()`:

```
class Status {
    // ...
    public function __toString()
    {
        // It is vital here to enforce the type of $this->name into the constructor
        // __toString() must return a string
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

This way your code will look nice:

```
$pending = new Pending();
echo('The status is: '.$pending);

// Output:
// The status is: pending
```

Comment: Thank you for everything you wrote, it's very helpful and enlightening :).